# Is .htaccess files supposed to work even outside public_html?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web

I've always thought that .htaccess files do not work outside of the public_html directory. However, even when my .htaccess file is outside of the public_html folder, it affects the files within public_html.

This is my setup:

- **/home**

  - **/yca**

    - **/public_html**

      - **index.php**
      - *etc etc*
    - **/.htaccess** (this file *works* even though it is not inside public_html folder)

Is there a problem with my installation / configuration or Is .htaccess files supposed to work beyond the public_html directory?

Comment: .htaccess only affects on its directory and below it, but not up...

Comment: Actually this depends on how that public_html folder is mapped into the http servers document hierarchy. How do you access that folder from a client (browser)?

Comment: What is your DOCUMENT_ROOT in Apache config?

Comment: @arkascha, mydomain.com would show files in /home/yca/public_html. And subd1.mydomain.com would show files in /home/yca/public_html/subd1

Comment: @anubhava, echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; on subd1.mydomain.com gives /home/yca/public_html/subd1

Comment: Sorry, it still depends on how that http server is setup to access that content in your home folder. It might use an internal request which could lead to that `.htaccess` file being interpreted and considered. Impossible to say if you don't know the setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is  the correct way for .htaccess to work.  Your .htaccess file and your public_html folder are on the same level, so .htaccess will affect files in public_html.

What you have is identical to a .htaccess file in your webroot and expecting it to not affect any subdirectories.  It's supposed to.

If you do this it won't affect

- **/home**

  - **/yca**

    - **/public_html**

      - **index.php**
      - *etc etc*
    - **/private**

      - **/.htaccess** (Now this file won't affect public_html because its on a differnt level.)

Comment: My .htaccess is outside of my web root. Hmm, do you mean it's still supposed to work? So if I have a .htaccess file in my unix root directory right at the very top where every other single file resides, it would affect all my domains hosted on that computer?

Comment: I'd say a .htaccess file in any subdir of your apache webroot will do this yes.  Why did you put it there if you don't want it to affect your website?

Comment: And to confirm, you are saying that if the .htaccess is located in the `yca` folder, it **shouldn't** affect the stuff in `public_html` folder right?

Comment: No it will.  a .htaccess file placed in the yca folder will affect the yca folder and all folders below it.  Try it and see what happens

Answer (score 2):

In your directory tree your .htaccess seems to be in `/yca`. For a request to `domain.com/index.php`, it will check `/home/yca/public_html/.htaccess` and ALL htaccess in parent directories of that directory. That's why having a `.htaccess` in your www root works fine for requests to `domain.com/some/sub/directory/file.php`.

Comment: This is odd, do you mean that if I have a .htaccess file in my unix root directory right at the very top, it would affect *all* my domains?

Comment: In short: Yes, I think it does. It might however be wise to limit this by using the [AllowOverride-directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) in httpd.conf

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. That answer merely suggests that .htaccess is working because it's on the same level as the webroot, which is only part of the story. I was experiencing the same thing, and I wondered why an (accidental) .htaccess was influencing the configuration.